# firebase_crashlytics integration with flutter is not working stuck at We'll be listening for your app to communicate with our servers

Tags: firebase, flutter, crashlytics

i am trying to implement https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics plugin for my flutter app.

i followed every step given in https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics plugin but got stuck at firebase console page where it says **We'll be listening for your app to communicate with our servers.**

this is my initialization

```
void main(){
  Crashlytics.instance.enableInDevMode = true;
  FlutterError.onError = Crashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

and i am forcing app crash on click of button like

```
Crashlytics.instance.crash();
```

when i click on button i can see log in debug console

```
flutter: firebase_crashlytics: Error reported to Crashlytics.
```

but firebase console not showing any logs and stuck at above mentioned page.
can someone help please.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here on SO, I recommend searching/posting on the Flutterfire issues section directly https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues